# is WYSiHat some how based on YUI

Tags: javascript, yui, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, wysihat

I have a simple question. IS WYSiHat WYSIWYG rich text editor some how based on YUI? As far as I understand it is not, but some how the way it is coded is very similar to YUI.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it has Prototype listed as a dependency, I wouldn't think so.